# What can make passing init=/path/to/program to the kernel not start program as init?

Tags: linux, init

I'm trying to debug an init script on a Linux system; I'm trying to pass `init=/bin/sh` to the kernel to make it start `sh` without starting `init` so I can run through the init sequence manually.

What I've found is that the kernel is starting `init` anyway. During bootup, one of the printk messages is the command line, and that is showing that the line is being set properly; in addition, I can affect other things using the kernel command line. I have checked to make sure the path exists; it does.

This is a busybox system, and init is a symlink to busybox; so to make sure busybox doesn't do strange magic when its PID is 1, I also tried running a non-busybox program as init; that didn't work, either. It seems that no matter what I do, init is run.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: What is the base distro that is using busybox for `init`? They may simply be ignoring the command line... you may want to [examine the initrd](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/Initrd#Examining_an_initrd) and see what the scripts are actually doing.

Comment: It's not any distro - it's my own build; which is why I'm trying to debug the init scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at Linux kernel source, I see that if the file /init exists, the kernel will always attempt to run it on the assumption that it's doing a ramdisk boot.  Check your system to see if /init exists, if it does, then that's probably your problem.

Comment: Actually, it checks `execute_command` first, which comes from the kernel command line `init=` parameter. If it can't execute it, it prints a warning and tries to run `init` in various locations. This is in `init/main.c` in the function `init_post()`. I looked through the kernel printk messages and found the warning in my kernel's output, so now I have to figure out why it can't start /bin/sh or anything else that I try to start.

Comment: The code I looked at (v3.2.2 I think) checked set ramdisk_execute_command if it was unset and then tried to run it, so you must not be that current.  Too bad, because I didn't see anything else that would explain it.

Comment: You must use `rdinit` when booting from ramdisk apparently: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/430614/32558

Answer (score 16):

**initrd shenanigans**

If you are using initrd or initramfs, keep in mind the following:

- `rdinit=` is used instead of `init=`
- if `rdinit=` is not given, the attempted default paths are: `/sbin/init`, `/etc/init`, `/bin/init` and `/bin/sh` but not `/init`

  When not using initrd, `/init` is the first path tried, followed by the others.

v4.15 RTFS: everything is contained inside the https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.15/init/main.c file.

First we learn that:

- `execute_comand` is whatever is passed to: `init=`
- `ramdisk_execute_command` is whatever is passed to: `rdinit=`

as can be seen from:

```
static int __init init_setup(char *str)
{
    unsigned int i;

    execute_command = str;
    /*
    * In case LILO is going to boot us with default command line,
    * it prepends "auto" before the whole cmdline which makes
    * the shell think it should execute a script with such name.
    * So we ignore all arguments entered _before_ init=... [MJ]
    */
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_INIT_ARGS; i++)
        argv_init[i] = NULL;
    return 1;
}
__setup("init=", init_setup);

static int __init rdinit_setup(char *str)
{
    unsigned int i;

    ramdisk_execute_command = str;
    /* See "auto" comment in init_setup */
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_INIT_ARGS; i++)
        argv_init[i] = NULL;
    return 1;
}
__setup("rdinit=", rdinit_setup);
```

where `__setup` is a magic way of handling up command line parameters.

`start_kernel`, the kernel "entry point", calls `rest_init`, which "calls" `kernel_init` on a thread:

```
pid = kernel_thread(kernel_init, NULL, CLONE_FS);
```

Then, `kernel_init` does:

```
static int __ref kernel_init(void *unused)
{
    int ret;

    kernel_init_freeable();

    [...]

    if (ramdisk_execute_command) {
        ret = run_init_process(ramdisk_execute_command);
        if (!ret)
            return 0;
        pr_err("Failed to execute %s (error %d)\n",
            ramdisk_execute_command, ret);
    }

    [...]

    if (execute_command) {
        ret = run_init_process(execute_command);
        if (!ret)
            return 0;
        panic("Requested init %s failed (error %d).",
            execute_command, ret);
    }
    if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh"))
        return 0;

    panic("No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. "
        "See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.");
}
```

and `kernel_init_freeable` does:

```
static noinline void __init kernel_init_freeable(void)
{

    [...]

    if (!ramdisk_execute_command)
        ramdisk_execute_command = "/init";

    if (sys_access((const char __user *) ramdisk_execute_command, 0) != 0) {
        ramdisk_execute_command = NULL;
        prepare_namespace();
    }
```

TODO: understand `sys_access`.

Also note that there are further differences between ram inits and non-ram inits, e.g. console handling: [Difference in execution of init with embedded vs. external initramfs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208515/difference-in-execution-of-init-with-embedded-vs-external-initramfs/430617#430617)

Answer (score 4):

On

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt

I found:

> When debugging a normal root filesystem, it's nice to be able to boot with
>   "init=/bin/sh".  The initramfs equivalent is "rdinit=/bin/sh", and it's
>   just as useful.

So probably try ridinit=/bin/sh

Answer (score 0):

You can custom your Linux kernel and recompile it. For 4.9 kernel, Edit the function "kernel_init" in init/main.c and try to run the following line first:

```
try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh")
```

In addition, It might be caused by the kernel parameters passed by BootLoader.