# What exactly does init do?

Tags: linux, startup, init

I am creating a linux distro and now I need an init program. I can code in c really well and I know quite a bit about linux (not much but I've been using arch linux for development for 4 years), so I thought I should try writing my own basic init script in C. I was just wondering, what tasks does init do to set the system up for a simple shell? (When I ask "what does init do?", I do know what init is and what it's for. I just don't know what tasks it does.)

I don't need code and I possibly don't even need basic commands but I *do* need the order that they are run in.

Comment: You can use whatever interpreter you like for SysV-style init scripts, including Perl, awk, bash, (t)csh, native binaries, ... Bash is normally used because it's virtually guaranteed to be available on the system where such scripts are deployed at the relevant point in the boot process, not because there is some coupling between SysVinit and bash. SysVinit defines the contract and each script is free to implement that contract in any way its developer sees fit.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## System 5 `init` will tell you only a small part of the story.

There's a sort of myopia that affects the Linux world.  People think that they use a thing called "System 5 `init`", and that is both what is traditional and the best place to start.  Neither is in fact the case.

Tradition isn't in fact what such people say it to be, for starters.  System 5 `init` and System 5 `rc` date to AT&T UNIX System 5, which was almost as far after the first UNIX as we are now (say) after the first version of Linux-Mandrake.

1st Edition UNIX only had `init`. It did not have `rc`. The 1st Edition assembly language `init` ([whose code](https://code.google.com/p/unix-jun72/source/browse/trunk/src/cmd/init.s) has been [restored and made available by Warren Toomey et al.](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix09/tech/full_papers/toomey/toomey.pdf)) directly spawned and respawned 12 `getty` processes, mounted 3 hardwired filesystems from a built-in table, and directly ran a program from the home directory of a user named `mel`. The `getty` table was also directly in the program image.

It was another decade after UNIX System 5 that the so-called "traditional" Linux init system came along.  In 1992, Miquel van Smoorenburg (re-)wrote a Linux `init`+`rc`, and their associated tools, which people now refer to as "System 5 `init`", even though it isn't actually the software from UNIX System 5 (and isn't just `init`).

System  5 `init`/`rc` isn't the best place to start, and even if one adds on knowledge of systemd that doesn't cover half of what there is to know. There's been a lot of work in the area of init system design (for Linux and the BSDs) that has happened in the past two decades alone. All sorts of engineering decisions have been discussed, made, designed, implemented, and practised.  The commercial Unices did a lot, too.

## Existing systems to study and and learn from

Here is an incomplete list of some of the major init systems *other than* those two, and one or two of their (several) salient points:

- Joachim Nilsson's [finit](http://troglobit.com/finit.html) went the route of using a more human-readable configuration file.
- Felix von Leitner's [minit](http://www.fefe.de/minit/) went for a filesystem-is-the-database configuration system, small memory footprints, and start/stop dependencies amongst things that `init` starts.
- Gerrit Pape's [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) went for what I have previously described as *the just spawn four shell scripts* approach.
- [InitNG](http://initng.org/) aimed to have dependencies, named targets, multiple configuration files, and a more flexible configuration syntax with a whole load more settings for child processes.
- [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) went for a complete redesign, modelling the system not as services and interdependencies at all, but as events and jobs triggered by them.
- The design of [nosh](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/nosh.html) includes pushing all of the service management out (including even the `getty` spawning and zombie reaping) into a separate service manager, and *just* handling operating-system-specific "API" devices/symlinks/directories and system events.
- [sinit](http://git.suckless.org/sinit) is a very simple init. It executes `/bin/rc.init` whose job it is to start programs, mount filesystem, etc. For this you can use something like [minirc](http://github.com/hut/minirc).

Moreover, about 10 years ago, there was discussion amongst daemontools users and others of using `svscan` as process #1, which led to projects like [Paul Jarc's svscan as process 1 study](http://code.dogmap.org/svscan-1/), [Gerrit Pape's ideas](http://smarden.org/pape/djb/daemontools/noinit.html), and [Laurent Bercot's svscan as process 1](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-svscan-1.html).

Which brings us to what process #1 programs do.

## What process #1 programs do

Notions of what process #1 is "supposed" to do are by their natures subjective.  A meaningful *objective* design criterion is what process #1 *at minimum must* do. The kernel imposes several requirements on it. And there are always some operating-system-specific things of various kinds that it has to do. When it comes to what process #1 has *traditionally* done, then we are not at that minimum and never really have been.

There are several things that various operating system kernels and other programs demand of process #1 that one simply cannot escape.

People will tell you that `fork()`ing things and acting as the parent of orphaned processes is the prime function of process #1.  Ironically, this is untrue.  Dealing with orphaned processes is (with recent Linux kernels, as explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/5132) a part the system that one can largely factor out of process #1 into other processes, such as a dedicated *service manager*.  All of these are service managers, that run outwith process #1:

- the IBM AIX `srcmstr` program, the [System Resource Controller](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/src.htm)
- Gerrit Pape's [`runsvdir`](http://smarden.org/runit/runsvdir.8.html) from runit
- Daniel J. Bernstein's [`svscan`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svscan.html) from daemontools, Adam Sampson's `svscan` from [freedt](http://offog.org/code/freedt/), Bruce Guenter's [`svscan`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/svscan.8.html) from daemontools-encore, and Laurent Bercot's [`s6-svscan`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-svscan.html) from s6
- Wayne Marshall's [`perpd`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=perpd.8) from perp
- the Service Management Facility in Solaris 10
- the `service-manager` from nosh

Similarly, as explained at https://superuser.com/a/888936/38062, the whole `/dev/initctl` idea doesn't need to be anywhere near process #1.  Ironically, it is the highly centralized systemd that demonstrates that it can be moved out of process #1.

Conversely, the mandatory things for `init`, that people usually forget in their off-the-top-of-the-head designs, are things such as handling `SIGINT`, `SIGPWR`, `SIGWINCH`, and so forth sent from the kernel and enacting the various system state change requests sent from programs that "know" that certain signals to process #1 mean certain things.  (For example: As explained at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196471/5132, BSD toolsets "know" that `SIGUSR1` has a specific meaning.)

There are also once-off initialization and finalization tasks that one cannot escape, or will suffer greatly from not doing, such as mounting ["API" filesystems](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/) or flushing the filesystem cache.

The basics of dealing with "API" filesystems are little different to the operation of `init` rom 1st Edition UNIX: One has a list of information hardwired into the program, and one simply `mount()`s all of the entries in the list.  You'll find this mechanism in systems as diverse as BSD (sic!) `init`, through the nosh `system-manager`, to systemd.

## "set the system up for a simple shell"

As you have observed, `init=/bin/sh` doesn't get "API" fileystems mounted, crashes in an ungainly fashion with no cache flush when one types `exit` (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195978/5132), and in general leaves it to the (super)user to manually do the actions that make the system minimally usable.

To see what one actually has no choice but to do in process #1 programs, and thus set you on a good course for your stated design goal, your best option is to look at the overlaps in the operation of Gerrit Pape's runit, Felix von Leitner's minit, and the `system-manager` program from the nosh package.  The former two show two attempts to be minimalist, yet still handle the stuff that it is impossible to avoid.

The latter is useful, I suggest, for its extensive manual entry for the `system-manager` program, which details exactly what "API" filesystems are mounted, what initialization tasks are run, and what signals are handled; in a system that *by design* has the system manager just spawn three other things (the service manager, an accompanying logger, and the program to run the state changes) and only do the unavoidable in process #1.

Comment: Awesome answer and very informative. But I'm asking myself where in this big picture is OSX `launchd`. Sometimes people forget entirely that OSX is a (great) a member of the large *nix family.

Comment: @DavAlPi: I don't agree with your premise re *"OSX **is** a great member..."*, but can concede to **was**  :)    But wrt your question, I've thought that `launchd` was more like `systemd` than `init`. But there's a decent Wikipedia article on it if you're still interested. In particular see the [History section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd#History)

Answer (score 4):

System V init on Debian (there are other variants and variations) does the following:

- When entering a runlevel, it calls scripts in `/etc/rcX.d/S*` in alphanumeric order, where `X` is the runlevel.  These scripts should setup the runlevel.  Typical setup is starting daemons and performs setup tasks for that run level.  This is a one-time thing done when entering the runlevel.
- While in a run level, it starts daemons that are listed in the `/etc/inittab` as needing to be active during that run level.  If those daemons stop running, it restarts them.  While you can have any daemon you want managed by `init`, at a minimum you want a few `getty`'s so you can log in.  `getty` exits once a log in is completed, then `init` restarts it, providing a fresh login prompt.

  - If the daemon restarts too many times in too short of a time, it stops trying to restart it for a while.
  - Just because something was started by the kickoff scripts when entering the run level does not make `init` automatically try to keep it running.  You need to specify that separately in the `/etc/inittab`.
- When exiting a runlevel, it calls scripts in `/etc/rcX.d/K*` in alphanumeric order, where `X` is the runlevel.  A way to implement shutdown or reboot is to define a runlevel for those events and make the last task executed the `halt` or `reboot` command.
- It will call executables in response to certain events, such as power events or Ctrl-Alt-Del.
- It listens on a socket, if it receives certain messages it will change runlevel.

So you can use `init` as rudimentary service manager if you want, but it's main task these days is to keep `getty`'s available so a user can login, and kick off runlevel transitions.

> I was just wondering, what tasks does init do to set the system up for a simple shell?

Whatever you want.  On Debian, in each `/etc/rcX.d` directory is a symlink to a script in `/etc/init.d` and you can fully customize or remove those scripts.  The order is established by preceding each script with a `00`, `01`, etc.

You can also specify a `-b` option to `init` (i.e. via kernel command line) if you just want `init` to spawn a shell.  When you exit the shell, `init` dies and when `init` dies, the kernel will panic.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute bare minimum that init must do is run at least one other program and not ever exit. If init exits the system crashes. I suppose that even running the one other program is not strictly necessary, but If you don't do that init would have to be responsible for doing every thing that the system is expected to do, or it would not be very useful.

Comment: I've had buggy Linux systems where PID 1 crashed but the system basically kept running. How bad PID 1 crashing is may depend on the kernel version.

Answer (score 2):

**`init` can do whatever you want**

init is an arbitrary executable called by the Linux kernel at the end of the boot process (and the only one such executable).

It is normally implemented as an ELF executable, but it can even be a shell script with `chmod +x`: [Can the init process be a shell script in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174062/init-as-a-shell-script/395375#395375)

Typical implementations like sysemd will read configuration files, ofen `/etc/initrc`, and then fork a bunch of userland processes based on those configurations,  to implement various aspects of the system.

However, this is completely implementation specific, and therefore you question cannot be answered without specifying a specific implementation. For example, I've been playing with a `init` process that simply does a [`reboot` syscall](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/e45ab63177f940f5c58d02b479abc6853ad2946f/kernel_module/user/poweroff.c#L11) for education purposes.

The Linux kernel simply looks for the executable at the path `/init` and other similar paths by default, but this can be overridden by the `init=` Linux kernel command line parameter. The exact defaults used are discussed at: [What can make passing init=/path/to/program to the kernel not start program as init?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30414/what-can-make-passing-init-path-to-program-to-the-kernel-not-start-program-as-i/430614#430614)

One great way to play around with `init` is to use QEMU, since you can pass the kernel command line parameters to QEMU from the QEMU command line
with the `-append` option, and without the fear of bricking your desktop.

Here is my [minimal fully automated Buildroot + QEMU setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/e45ab63177f940f5c58d02b479abc6853ad2946f#custom-init) that makes it very easy to play around with your own inits to demystify the matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are committed to the modular "do one thing and do it well" principle, then an `init` programme should start processes.

### Start Processes

It should be executed once the kernel has been successfully decompressed, taking care of all the rudimentary tasks involved in initialising all the initial processes that a system requires to operate (such as mounting drives found in /etc/fstab, bringing up network interfaces, and so on).

Since the process of booting up and shutting down are essentially inverse of one another, it is common for an init programme to also ensure that processes are stopped upon a shutdown command.

### Stop Processes

This means it must stop processes according to that process's man page (in other words, not just a blatant `kill -9`, it should bring the process down in the way that it wants to be ended), unmount drives, and ultimately issue the final power down command.

### References

A good reference for how this is done by others is to look at [Slackware's /etc/rc.d scripts](http://mirror.lagoon.nc/pub/slackware/slackware64-14.1/source/a/sysvinit-scripts/scripts), and also at a simple init system that already exists, like  [ninit](http://riemann.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/ninit/) (a successor to minit). It has process supervision (meaning that if a process dies, it is relaunched), which is arguably not init's job, but it's still quite basic and simple to understand, especially through the author's sample scripts.