# Why do I have mounted partitions that do not appear in /etc/fstab?

Tags: debian, mount, fstab

My `/etc/fstab` has only two lines: root partition and debugfs, while `/etc/mtab` has much more, in addition to these two, like (sysfs, proc, udev, devpts, tmpfs, cgroup, ...).

Where do the additional mount points come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those mounts are often performed by the initramfs/initrd scripts or other early-boot system initialization scripts, or on distributions that are fully using `systemd`, by `.mount` systemd unit files executed by either the real `systemd` or by the mini-systemd environment within the initramfs.

For example, Debian 9 has the following `.mount` units by default:

```
/lib/systemd/system/dev-hugepages.mount
/lib/systemd/system/dev-mqueue.mount
/lib/systemd/system/proc-fs-nfsd.mount
/lib/systemd/system/proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
/lib/systemd/system/run-rpc_pipefs.mount
/lib/systemd/system/sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
/lib/systemd/system/sys-kernel-config.mount
/lib/systemd/system/sys-kernel-debug.mount
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement that partitions must be listed in `/etc/fstab`.  After all, you can just run `mount` with everything explicitly specified in command-line arguments and mount another filesystem, without using anything from `/etc/fstab`.

However, what you are seeing are things that have been automatically mounted for you, already.

These days on Debian, most of these file systems (they are not partitions as there is no disk backing these file systems) are created/mounted by `systemd`.

Many of them are what the `systemd` people refer to as "API filesystems" because they effectively are part of the API that is provided by the kernel to applications.  [A list of such filesystems is hardwired into the `systemd` code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/de7436b02badc82200dc127ff190b8155769b8e7/src/core/mount-setup.c#L59).  Observe that it is not in synch with the `systemd` documentation.

[Mounting API filesystems is one of the usual tasks of the system management softwares that run as process #1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/197472/5132), even outwith Linux, from BSD (sic!) `init` to `systemd`.

- The API filesystems mounted by FreeBSD `init` are not documented, but like `systemd` [can be found in its code](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/11.2.0/sbin/init/init.c?view=markup#l359).
- The API filesystems mounted by [`runit-init`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/runit-init) on Debian and by [van Smoorenburg `rc`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/sysv-rc) are not documented.  They can be found in a common `rc` script file, [`mountkernfs.sh`](https://sources.debian.org/src/sysvinit/2.88dsf-59.10/debian/src/initscripts/etc/init.d/mountkernfs.sh/), that both systems use.  (Note that this is one of the van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts that `systemd` explicitly masks, because it is entirely spuerseded by what `systemd` does.)
- The API filesystems mounted by the `system-manager` in the nosh toolset, both for Linux and for the BSDs, are listed in its manual page (q.v.) accessible with `man system-manager`.

## Further reading

- *[API FileSystems](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/)*.  Freedesktop.org.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[API filesystems and early devices](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/system-manager.html#idp60555984)".  `system-manager`.  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Comment: where are the systemd mount points defined?

Comment: Probably in the `systemd` source code.