# Difference in execution of init with embedded vs. external initramfs?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, initramfs

I'm building a very minimal Linux system that just consists of the kernel (v4.1-rc5) and an initramfs populated with busybox (v1.23.2). It works fine for the most part, but I observe a difference in behavior of command execution in /init whether I'm using an embedded initramfs vs. an external one.

The /init script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

dmesg -n 1

mount -t devtmpfs none /dev
mount -t sysfs none /sys
mount -t proc none /proc
echo "Welcome"
while true
do
    setsid cttyhack /bin/sh
done
```

Then I either set the CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE option in the kernel .config to the directory containing all the folders for the initramfs, or I run

```
find . | cpio -H newc -o | gzip > ../rootfs.cpio.gz
```

to build it.

When I then compile the kernel, either with or without CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE set, I end up with two variants of my system:

1. bzImage with initramfs embedded
2. bzImage + rootfs.cpio.gz (external initramfs)

when I now start those using `qemu`

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -kernel bzImage
```

or

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -kernel bzImage -initrd rootfs.cpio.gz
```

I get the following difference in behavior:

with version 2 (external initramfs) everything works fine, "Welcome" is displayed and I get a prompt. With version 1 however (embedded initramfs) I get the warning

```
unable to open an initial console
```

"Welcome" is not displayed, and I get my prompt.

As far as I understand the process, those two versions of initramfs should contain the same files, since I build it (or have the kernel build it) from an identical folder.

I wonder if anyone can help me with an explanation for this behavior?

*** UPDATE ***

as mikeserv said in the comments, The kernel includes a minimal embedded initramfs per default. This is still present when using an external one, but gets overwritten if you embed your own. I found that contrary to the specification, this is indeed not empty, but contains a dev folder, a root folder and the /dev/console device. This device then gets used when using an external initramfs, but overwritten if you embed your own. So you have to include the /dev/console device in your initramfs source `mknod -m 622 initramfs_src/dev/console c 5 1` when embedding your own.

Thanks a lot to mikeserv, frostschutz and JdeBP for helping me get my head around that!

Comment: What are the permissions set to on `/dev/console` on your builtin one? I think the difference might be about *who* does the packing in the two cases.

Comment: A similar question is of course http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437995/ .

Comment: @mikeserv the console device has identical permissions and ownership in both builds.

Comment: @JdeBP I'm not sure if its that similar, since in both cases I boot, get a prompt and have a console device. Only that in one init executes the echo and in the other it can't.

Comment: @JdeBP ok, adding the console device in /dev of the initramfs with `mknod -m 622 console c 5 1` actually works in getting rid of the problem in the embedded version. That leaves me still puzzled why the behavior is different for the two cases, in that the external initramfs has its console device ready already when its supposed to execute the "echo"

Comment: How could the permissions have been the same in initramfs if you didn't even have it at all?

Comment: @mikeserv I had the device in all the cases at the point where I get the command prompt and can check it. For some reason however, its not present for the embedded version at the point where it executes the "echo" within /init, while for the external one it is

Comment: @mikeserv I think I missunderstood the question. The initramfs itself didn't have console devices in any case. /dev was populated through `mount -t devtmpfs none /dev` in init, which for some reason shows different results when using an embedded initramfs vs. external

Comment: Well, even when you use an external initramfs the kernel *still* includes an internal one - it's the [mount point](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt). *The 2.6 kernel build process always creates a gzipped cpio format initramfs
archive and links it into the resulting kernel binary.  By default, this
archive is empty (consuming 134 bytes on x86).* You should read that whole link.

Comment: @mikeserv I did read that, but thought it would have no effect since the archive is supposedly empty. So the default initramfs carries the /dev/console mountpoint that is used by the external one, but removed when I use my own embedded one? Would this have effects on populating anything else (sys, proc, other devs)?

Comment: I dunno man, does it? Pull it all apart and find out. There *will be* differences, though. So do some `cmp`ing and `diff`ing until you figure it out. It's only a few kb in either case - you just need to dig, dude.

Comment: Can you update the question with your final init file? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are they really identical?

The built-in one you can find in `/usr/src/linux/usr/initramfs_data.cpio.gz` or extract it from the bzImage as described here: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Salvaging

If you use that built-in one and use it as external one instead, does it work?

If it's still different, is the kernel itself identical? (compare `/proc/config.gz` for both)

There should be some difference. I'm not aware that the kernel cares where the initramfs came from. I'd sooner suspect `qemu` of using different settings when passing the `-initrd` parameter...

On a sidenote, your `/init` looks like its spawning infinite shells to me. `setsid` is not `exec`. Am I wrong?

Comment: This answer seems to be all questions.

Comment: @JdeBP: You're not thinking fourth-dimensionally!

Comment: @frostschutz Thanks a lot for your reply! When I use the initramfs that the kernel builds (usr/initramfs_data.cpio.gz) as external it works fine as well! Also, when I supply the kernel that was compiled with the embedded initramfs with an external one, the warning appears, even though the external should overwrite the embedded (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt). So its probably also not qemu -initrd but something within the kernel itself. I changed nothing other then CONFIG_INITRAMFS_SOURCE though..

Comment: @frostschutz Answering your ```On a sidenote, your /init looks like its spawning infinite shells to me. setsid is not exec. Am I wrong?```: The loop mimics getty or similar tools, since the call the `sh` blocks until that shell exits.

Comment: @stefanjunker and that would be fine, except setsid doesn't block at all...

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in how Buildroot 2018.02 deals with this.

Whenever you use initramfs (`BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_INITRAMFS=y`) or initrd (`BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_CPIO=n`), it adds the following `/init` to your rootfs https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2018.02/fs/cpio/init

```
#!/bin/sh
# devtmpfs does not get automounted for initramfs
/bin/mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs /dev
exec 0</dev/console
exec 1>/dev/console
exec 2>/dev/console
exec /sbin/init "$@"
```

The copy is done by https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/blob/2018.02/fs/cpio/cpio.mk :

```
# devtmpfs does not get automounted when initramfs is used.
# Add a pre-init script to mount it before running init
define ROOTFS_CPIO_ADD_INIT
    if [ ! -e $(TARGET_DIR)/init ]; then \
        $(INSTALL) -m 0755 fs/cpio/init $(TARGET_DIR)/init; \
    fi
endef
```

It is also useful to know that the init path is `/init` for initramfs, unlike `/sbin/init` otherwise: [What can make passing init=/path/to/program to the kernel not start program as init?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30414/what-can-make-passing-init-path-to-program-to-the-kernel-not-start-program-as-i/430614#430614)